# "office 365" "API" "calendar data report"

Tags: api, calendar, resources, report, office365

I am looking for a way to generate a report from Office 365 calendar data for our staff who are all using Office 365. I looked at the information at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605896%28v=office.15%29.aspx#bkCalItems which is for an API for calendar data. But, it is not clear if I would really have access to the DATA in the calendar - or if it would be "access protected". If I have the right security / Azure Active Directory, would it be possible to write a report of calendar data for all the office staff? I don't want multiple calendars or to sign in multiple times and export data for each person.  I want one integrated report showing a calendar date and then for that date, assignments for each person with the description and from/to times.

Hope this is clear - and thank you for  your guidance.

-j

Answer (score 0):

In general the Office API tools are built for clients to get access to their own data. Not for a user to access other users data. But there's a way you can do what you want.

The users that is gonna generate the report is probably some sort of admin. So you could grant that user Full Access to everybodys mailbox (by use of the delegation feature). You can do so with this powershell:

`Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -Filter {(RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (Alias -ne 'Admin')} | Add-MailboxPermission -User admin -AccessRights fullaccess -InheritanceType all -AutoMapping $False`

Source: http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/gg709759.aspx

After that you can with the standard Exchange Rest API access each individual users calendar

First you get the list of users by calling:
https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Users

Then you can get the calendar items for each user by calling:
https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Users('EMAILOF@USER')/Calendar

I don't really like the approach as I don't think admins should need full permission to just to read the user's calendar. But apparently even though calendar sharing is enabled it doesn't mean that the calendar REST endpoint is available to users other than the owner of the mailbox, so I don't see any other way. Unless you want to use the ics format used by calendar sharing, but then your question is in the wrong category.